# php unable to perform mysql query escaping

Tags: php, mysql, sql, escaping

I'm trying to set query by parsing URL and set baseline:

```
class CatalogHandler extends DB{ 
public function getCatalog(){
    $URL=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $catalog=basename($URL);
    return $catalog;
}
....}
```

This returns 'cartridges' that's what I need
So I'm setting mysql query to set metadata for a page

```
include('CatalogHandler.php');
include('DBconfig.php');

$config = new DBconfig('localhost','setuser','a11235813b','setua');
$catalog = new CatalogHandler($config);
$catalogname=$catalog->getCatalog();
$catalog->openConnection(); //Nothing special just open mysqlconnection
$query="SELECT * FROM metaandtitlecatalogs WHERE Cat in ('".$catalogname."');"; //Problem goes here
$sql=$catalog->query($query); //added to the end of the issue
$hasRows = $catalog->countRows($sql); //here I'm getting Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in \home\localhost\www\setua\DB.php
echo "hasrows:".$hasRows;
```

Here are functions I used.

```
class DB{
public function query($query){
    $query = str_replace("}", "", $query);
    $query = str_replace("{", $this->config->prefix, $query);
    try{
        if(empty($this->connection)){
            $this->openConnection();

            if($this->config->connector == "mysql"){
                $this->lastQuery = mysql_query($this->ecapeString($query));
            }
            elseif($this->config->connector == "mysqli"){
                $this->lastQuery = mysqli_query($this->connection, $this->ecapeString($query));
            }
            $this->closeConnection();

            return $this->lastQuery;
        }
        else{
            if($this->config->connector == "mysql"){
                $this->lastQuery = mysql_query($this->ecapeString($query));
            }
            elseif($this->config->connector == "mysqli"){
                $this->lastQuery = mysqli_query($this->connection, $this->ecapeString($query));
            }
            return $this->lastQuery;
        }
    }
    catch(exception $e){
        return $e;
    }
public function countRows($result){
    try{
        if($this->config->connector == "mysql"){
            return mysql_num_rows($result);
        }
        elseif($this->config->connector == "mysqli"){
            return mysqli_num_rows($result);
        }
    }
    catch(exception $e){
        return $e;
    }
}
}

}
```

Also I think it is important, In case when query becomes with "...Where ID in (1)" everything goes smoothly. Probably this is an issue with escaping as if hardcoded name is inserted instead of '".$catalogname."' problem appears. Tried to use and escape double quotes - reproduces :(
Preforming this query directly in DB returns appropriate result

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the method ecapeString() of your class, but I think you misunderstood the issue of escaping. Not the entire sql statement is to be quoted, but values, if you concatenate a string. In your case the result statement will be something like

```
SELECT * FROM metaandtitlecatalogs WHERE Cat in (\'cartridges\');
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM metaandtitlecatalogs WHERE Cat in ('cartridges');
```

It would be a great idea to use only mysqli or PDO with prepared statements and parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try suggestion of yours this evening and provide you with a respone :)